# How to nest quantile() function within apply() function in R or RStudio

Tags: r, console, rstudio, apply, quantile

How can I nest a quantile() within a tapply() in R Studio?

**Given**:

```
tapply(data$x,data$y, quantile)
```

This works, but it delivers standard quin-tiles. I want to choose custom percentiles. How can I incorporate something like this (below) into the above line of script?

```
quantile(data$x, c(0.1,.2,.8,0.9), na.rm=TRUE)
```

When I attempt to merge these, I receive the error message "match.fun(FUN)...not a function"

Any ideas? Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`tapply(data$x, data$y, quantile, probs=c(0.1,.2,.8,0.9), na.rm=TRUE)` ?